# Knockout js visible binding not working for secondary variable, depending on which drop down is selected should show message. First instance works

Tags: select, knockout.js, binding, observable, dropdown

I have a form which has 2 dropdowns questions.

Depending what the user answers, depends what will happen.

So for example
Are you human? The person answers yes and then another question show asking if they are employed, if they say yes to this then a sign up form will show.

If they say no to either question then some sorry cant sign you up text would show, with a form reset option ideally.

The first question seems to work fine, The issue is, it shows all messages for the second question which should be hidden until the value is selected and only one message should show.

```
Are you human?<br><select data-bind='value:thisSelect'>
  <option value='none'>Select answer</option>
  <option value='yes'>Yes</option>
  <option value='no'>No</option>

</select>
<p data-bind="visible:thisSelect() === 'yes'">
  Are you employed?<br>
  <select data-bind='value:currentSelect'>
    <option value='blank'>none</option>
    <option value='form'>show form</option>
    <option value='sorry'>Something else</option>
  </select></p>
<br><br>


<p data-bind="visible:currentSelect() === 'blank'"> </p>
<p data-bind="visible:currentSelect() === 'form'">Hello, now display the sign up form</p>
<p data-bind="visible:currentSelect() === 'sorry'">Goodbye</p>
```

And my Knockout JS

```
var testing = {
  thisSelect: ko.observable()
};
ko.applyBindings(testing);



var test = {
  currentSelect: ko.observable()
};
ko.applyBindings(test);
```

My Js fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/Chazlie/sdpayfo7/12/

Another version I tried is here http://jsfiddle.net/Chazlie/2exnjm4t/24/ but this just replaces the message from the first question so is not what I was hoping it would do.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is struggling with the same issue, I have solved this with the following, I believe the issue was that I was trying to call the bindings twice, instead of creating one variable and controlling it all there.

```
 Are you human?<br><select data-bind="value: selectedChoice">
  <option value="none">Select answer</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>

</select>
<p data-bind="visible: selectedChoice() === 'yes'">
  Are you employed?<br>
  <select data-bind="value: currentSelect">
    <option value="blank">none</option>
    <option value="form">show form</option>
    <option value="sorry">Something else</option>
  </select></p>
<br><br>


<p data-bind="visible:currentSelect() === 'blank'"> </p>
<p data-bind="visible:currentSelect() === 'form'">Hello, now display the sign up form</p>
<p data-bind="visible:currentSelect() === 'sorry'">Goodbye</p>

 <script> 
var viewModel = {
  
    selectedChoice: ko.observable("none"),
    currentSelect: ko.observable("none")

};


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

</script>
```